# ViewPager2, get current page viewholder

Tags: android

When a page is selected, I want to display an image with a description in the current page.

Specifically, in the activity

```java
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        viewPagerAdapter.showImage(position);
    }
});
```

In adapter

```java
public void showImage(int position) {
    ViewHolder holer = getHolder(position);
    holer.imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I want the same function as above...

Is there a good solution?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
(viewPager2.get(0) as RecyclerView).findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
```

or

```
(viewPager2.get(0) as RecyclerView).layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position)
```

Comment: How to use Kotlin's 'viewpager2.get' method in Java?

Comment: @and.s.s You can use `viewPager2.getChildAt(0)`

Comment: The `get()` just a extension func for `getChildAt(index) ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: $index, Size: $childCount")`

Comment: mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
 mViewPager.getChildAt(pos) ;

its always null

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli Don't change number in `viewPager2.get(0)`

Comment: Where is the `get` method on ViewPager2? I'm not getting any option to get an item at index.